# The dreaded "Declaration or statement expected" got me and I am dumbfounded

Tags: angular, typescript

I finished my first Angular Application and wanted to `build:aot:prod`, just to get slapped with the much discussed `Declaration or statement expected` error.

I happily ignored these errors during development because my app would still run, but with prod the love is over. I know this error got discussed a lot already, but this is my first typescript adventure and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Here's the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { StuffService } from '../services/stuff.service';
import { Stuff} from './model/stuff';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stuffList',
  templateUrl: './stuffList.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stuffList.component.scss'],
  providers: [StuffService]
})
export class StuffListComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadStuff();
  }
  public theStuff: Stuff[];

  constructor(private srv: StuffService) {

    public loadStuff() { // 'public' is squigglied and throws the error
      this.srv.getTheStuff()
      .subscribe(
          (theStuff) => this.theStuff = theStuff,
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
    }
}
```

I've got another error like that on a different component. It's pretty much the same, except the function gets called via (click) from the template.
If I can fix this I can finally launch the sucker onto the server :)

Comment: You need to close the `constructor(...) {` block *before* you declare the `public loadStuff()` method. While you can nest functions, you can't nest methods like this.

Comment: ......WHAT :|
Ok that fix was way simpler than I expected! Thanks a lot, that was it!

Comment: Glad to help. :) I've voted to close this as a typo, since it looks like an out of place delimiter.